# rvm gemset copy error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm working out the details to move from ruby-1.8.7 to ruby-1.9.2 with rvm and I'm hitting an issue with copying gems from one ruby to another and I wanted to see if anyone knew what the deal is and why it my be erring.

I already have 1.9.2 installed, but running `rvm gemset copy` is throwing an error.

```
[22:11][adamstacoviak:~]$ rvm gemset copy ruby-1.8.7-p249 ruby-1.9.2-p180
Copying gemset from ruby-1.8.7-p249 to ruby-1.9.2-p180
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Users/adamstacoviak/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/cache with non-directory /Users/adamstacoviak/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/cache
Making gemset for ruby-1.9.2-p180 pristine.
ERROR: Error running 'rvm gemset pristine' under ,
please read /Users/adamstacoviak/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gemset.pristine.log
```

... and here's the contents of the log file. I did update bundler as well since I saw that it mentioned `bundler-1.0.12` was not found. Updating to `bundler 1.0.12` didn't do the trick.

```
[2011-04-12 22:09:54] rvm gemset pristine # under ruby-1.9.2-p180
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::RemoteFetcher
Restoring gem(s) to pristine condition...
Cached gem for bundler-1.0.12 not found, attempting to fetch...
[2011-04-12 22:14:26] rvm gemset pristine # under ruby-1.9.2-p180
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::RemoteFetcher
Restoring gem(s) to pristine condition...
Cached gem for bundler-1.0.12 not found, attempting to fetch...
```

Any thoughts on why `rvm gemset copy` is erring?

Answer (score 3):

RVM is your friend and already knows how to upgrade your versions:

```
rvm help upgrade

Usage:

  rvm upgrade [source ruby] [destination ruby]

Description:

  Upgrades the specified (already installed) source ruby given to the
  given destination ruby version. Will migrate gemsets, wrappers, aliases
  and environment files.

  The process will prompt you at each stage - if the versions look incorrect,
  please cancel and perform it manually.


Examples:

  $ rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p136 1.9.2-p180

  $ rvm upgrade ree-2011.01 ree-2011-02
```

Type `rvm help ugrade` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply add the line to the file
>   /usr/bin/gem (may be different on a
>   mac) require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
>   after require 'rubygems'

[Found  this over here](http://www.nickpeters.net/2007/12/31/fix-for-uninitialized-constant-gemgemrunner-nameerror/)

Answer (score -1):

You could just use cp:

```
cp -R ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/* ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/
```

Comment: This will not ensure the gems are compatible.  See the Tin Man's answer

Comment: This can fall apart for gems with native drivers.